# How to copy a list of links from a page at once on Google Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

I want to copy all of the links from simple page of multiupload, like http://www.multiupload.com/B8VA5F2U4U.

As you can see there are some links but the links as they appear on the page are just "shortcuts" that are refering me to the site from multiupload.

Is there any fast way to be able get all of them with ctrl+c?

The simplest way I've thought about is to open them with snap link and then get the url of all open tabs(which include others as well but that what ive thought about).

I'm using Google Chrome, but if anything like that can be done in Firefox just tell me.

Comment: I lost you at your first sentence. What exactly doesn't work with CTRL+C or right clicking them and copying?

Comment: @Tom Wijsman he just wants to copy all links at once.

Comment: @screener: CTRL+A CTRL+C does exactly that. He needs to clarify why that is insufficient and what exactly he is looking for, because now we are basically just guessing around...

Comment: CTRL+A selects all the text on the page, and no, I am not guessing around. See the  page he linked to. MegaUpload uploads files to a list of different hosting providers. He just wants to copy the resulting links, which point to different hosting providers, for pasting them on some forum. Snap Links Plus does exactly what he wants -- copying a group of links from a webpage at once.

Comment: @screener: He said he wanted all the links. He can also just select them as one would select multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

**[Snap Links Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/SnapLinksPlus/)** for Firefox:

> With Snap Links Plus you can open multiple links in to new tabs **by drawing a selection rectangle**. You can also use it to click multiple check boxes, buttons and JavaScript links with a single action. Many other actions are available for the selected links such as open links in one new window, open each link in separate windows, **copy links to the clipboard** and more.

Opera users can just use the **[Links Panel](http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.00/en/panels.html#panels-links)** (press F4 to open the sidebar and then the plus sign to enable the links panel, if it's not already enabled):

> The links panel extracts all links in the current webpage so you can easily find images, music, video clips, zip files and other downloads, as well as links to other pages.
>
> Example: Type "mp3" in the "Quick find" field to find all mp3 files on the page.
>
> Tip: Click the "Lock" button to keep the current list of links even if you browse to other pages.

Comment: Quite clunky, (at least at my end) but with a bit of patience and careful mouse work this add-on does the job.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use unnecessary add-ons that slow down your browser and website loading times...

Just select all the links and copy them, you get something like this:

```
MultiUpload 
http://www.multiupload.com/B8VA5F2U4U

Megaupload  
http://www.multiupload.com/MU_B8VA5F2U4U

Uploadking  
http://www.multiupload.com/UK_B8VA5F2U4U

Uploadhere  
http://www.multiupload.com/UH_B8VA5F2U4U

Depositfiles    
http://www.multiupload.com/DF_B8VA5F2U4U

Hotfile 
http://www.multiupload.com/HF_B8VA5F2U4U

Zshare  
http://www.multiupload.com/ZS_B8VA5F2U4U

Filesonic   
http://www.multiupload.com/FC_B8VA5F2U4U

Fileserve   
http://www.multiupload.com/FS_B8VA5F2U4U

Wupload 
http://www.multiupload.com/WU_B8VA5F2U4U
```

If you only want the links, you can easily use nifty tricks / reg exps on it with something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/):

1. Bookmark all the lines containing `http://`.

   [image]
2. Use **Search > Bookmark > Inverse Bookmark**.

   [image]
3. Use **Search > Bookmark > Delete Bookmarked Lines**.

   [image]
4. You can even do this on the source code if you make two regular expressions that split multiple links from multiple lines onto one line as well as remove everything that's not a link.
5. Please note that these steps can be saved as a macro! ;)

Comment: Extensions like Snap Links Plus would never slow down a website, since they are called only if you press their specific button.

Comment: @screener: That's probably the case, but not all extensions are lazy loaded.

Comment: @screener: That's not true, they are loaded into memory (which requires disk access, fills the memory hash table which does slow down access) and hooks are called so the CPU is also affected. Most extensions are not lazily loaded as you can see with tools like Process Monitor. Fixing everything with extensions is one way to do it, learning more about a text editor to be able to do similar things is another one. As his question is pretty vague, he has both options available now...

Comment: @Tom Wijsman I agree that people should take the time to learn simple regular expressions, but consider that in this specific case, the links are also displayed as plain text, but if he was to copy a list of links with different labels instead of the URLs themselves (like "Part 1", "Part 2" etc.), he would need to manually  open the source code for that page, be able to find the link tags, remove all extra code to have only the URLs, and so on. The extension quickly copies a group of links no matter how they are being displayed for the web browser.

Comment: @screener: That's the matter of pressing shortcut keys and regular expressions, *easy*.

Comment: @screener, its slows the browser's loading at its first run. Unless you really need the extension a lot, dont install them or just keep them disabled until you use them.
then if there are "bookmarklet version" of same functionalities around, try using bookmarklets first.

Answer (score 0):

After nine years, if someone still needs the answer (I was the one, that's how I got here), there is nifty Chrome extension Linkclump.

You keep pressing <kbd>z</kbd> on the keyboard while selecting area with desired links with a left-click (other combinations are available). Release everything and the links are copied to the clipboard (or bookmarked, or opened in new tabs or new window).

Also, jDownloader can be used for this. Select text with links (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> for whole page, depending of the page content), press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+c, go to jD's Link Grabber, right-click and choose "Add New Links", new window with filtered links only will be opened. From that window you can manually copy now only the URLs.

Comment: JDownloader is really great in grabbing all the links in page and downloading them, but how about grabbing all links in the clipboard for text processing?

Answer (score 0):

I was testing several, and the best for me to do this is linkclump
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj?hl=en

Fast, clean,
and open source, that is always a plus, you can modify the code if you want to customize.

The only thing i miss is to be able to copy html text of the link, not only the link. To extract the title and its link.

Edited, yes, it does make this too. Perfect for me so.

Answer (score 0):

[Link Gopher (Firefox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-gopher/) is also good

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the main features of this program.